# Microsoft graph API getMemberGroups returns 400 bad request. What could be the reason?

Tags: java, azure, http, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

What could  be the reason for a 400 (Bad request response) when using [getMemberGroups API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryobject-getmembergroups?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)?
This is Java the code I'm using:

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);

List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<>();
urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("securityEnabledOnly", "true"));
request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));

HttpResponse response;
final StatusLine statusLine;
try {
    response = client.execute(request);
    statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
} catch (IOException e) {
    OutputUtil.printStacktrace(e);
    return null;
}
```

Where `url` is "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/getMemberGroups"

Another API call to "GET: memberOf" API does work. (with HttpGet object)

Comment: It seems that you're declaring the content to be JSON, but then send data using form encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
        String accessToken = "";
        HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/getMemberGroups");
        request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
        StringEntity requestEntity = new StringEntity("{\"securityEnabledOnly\": true}");
        request.setEntity(requestEntity);

        HttpResponse response;
        final StatusLine statusLine;

        response = client.execute(request);
        statusLine = response.getStatusLine();

        System.out.println(statusLine);
        System.out.println(new String(response.getEntity().getContent().readAllBytes()));
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thanks. My bad I didn't see it was a boolean.